# Why won't this method print the message in the exception parameter?

Tags: java, exception

I'm writing a method that is supposed to convert a string to an int if possible, and it throw an exception of not possible with a message. It throws the exception but it doesn't print the message, meaning it acts identically as it would were I to comment out the exception condition:

```
private static int throwsMethod() throws NumberFormatException{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("enter a number");
    String intNumber = s.next();

    Integer wrapperIntNumberConv = Integer.parseInt(intNumber);

    if(!(wrapperIntNumberConv instanceof Integer)){
        throw new NumberFormatException("can't make an int");
    }

    int fullConvertedNumber = (int) wrapperIntNumberConv;
    System.out.println(fullConvertedNumber);
    return fullConvertedNumber;
}
```

how can I do it without a try/catch block (I'm trying to learn exceptions and in this exercise, without a try/catch block) and get it to show the message?

edit: the reason the suggested answer that azro put in didn't solve my problem is because nothing there addreses a method with a throws someException() in the header

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Exceptions - Handling exceptions without try catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243887/java-exceptions-handling-exceptions-without-try-catch)

Comment: There's no way for `wrapperIntNumberConv` not to be an `Integer`, unless it holds `null` which it can't.

Comment: it could be "3D" or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is probably thrown at this line:

```
Integer wrapperIntNumberConv = Integer.parseInt(intNumber);
```

Because `parseInt` itself throws it if the string does not contain a parsable integer. ([Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)))

So the program does not reach your `if` in that case.

You need to wrap the line with `parseInt` inside a try-catch block to be able to throw an exception with your message:

```
String intNumber = s.next();
try {
    return Integer.parseInt(intNumber);
catch(NumberFormatException e) { // catch system's exception
    // throw new one with your message
    throw new NumberFormatException("can't make an int");
}
```

Or, you can check if the string contains a number (optional sign and digits), before calling `parseInt`:

```
String intNumber = s.next();
if (intNumber.matches("-?\\d+")) { // see: regular expressions
    return Integer.parseInt(intNumber);
} else {
    throw new NumberFormatException("can't make an int");
}
```

Comment: what would the try/catch look like?

Comment: @Derry I've added it to my answer now.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure to understand what you want: if the NumberFormatException is thrown, it can't reach the print instructions

```
int fullConvertedNumber = (int) wrapperIntNumberConv;
System.out.println(fullConvertedNumber);
return fullConvertedNumber;
```

so no message is printed.
If you want to print the "can't make an int" message you can print it before throwing the Exception or in the caller method via try-catch