# Execute the remaining code after handling exception in java?

Tags: java, exception

I may be silly. But I got interviewed and I was asked question regarding how you will run the remaining code after you will get the exception.

I gave number of approaches :

> 1. We can write the code in finally.
> 2. We can write the code in catch block. (They do not want to handle with these 2 approaches.)
> 3. We can use throw keyword. But I tried practically, It's not working.

I tried to explain them with throw statement too.

I have referred so many posts. But My doubt is still not cleared.

As example,

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      a(); // getting exception here...
      b(); // This method should executed after handling exception
  }
```

It will be helpful if you can suggest any approach on this. So I can understand it.

Comment: @Stultuske OP said the interviewer didn't want it to be handled in a try catch or finally

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Exceptions - Handling exceptions without try catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243887/java-exceptions-handling-exceptions-without-try-catch)

Comment: You're welcome to write code after the end of a catch block.

Comment: You can just execute your `b()` method after `try-catch` block. But it depends on requirements. If in your `catch` you can also get an exception AND `b()` should be executed anyway, then `finally` block is the only option.  P.S. on interviews it's often very useful to ask about special requirements, because you can never have one perfectly suitable solution / answer for a non specific problem / question.

Comment: I tried to explain above both approach we can write the method call in catch block or we can write a method call in finally. But they told they do not want it.

Comment: @KleoG missed that. but then, if the Interviewer wants the code like that, and catch/handle Exceptions without catching/handling them ...

Comment: @Jota.Toledo that doesn't solve this, or b() would have to be called from within that Handler (meaning it would not be called if a didn't throw an exception)

Comment: @Stultuske I agree with that, you're right - interviewer paradox

Comment: If b is only supposed to run when a throws an Exception, Jota's suggestion would indeed work, but let's just hope you don't have to pass additional parameters to b :)

Comment: i think you should check this link..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243887/java-exceptions-handling-exceptions-without-try-catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you caught your exception and handled it you can just run your `b()` method after try-catch block:

```
try {
  a();
} catch(Exception e) {
  handleMyError(e);
}
b();
```

This way the `a()` method executes, if exception is thrown it is caught and handled in the method `handleMyError(Exception e)` and then the execution continues `to b()` regardless whether the exception was thrown or not.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is almost the same as if method b() would have been invoked in "finally" block. The fifference is that with "finally" the ivocation of b() is guaranteed 100%. Without "finally" if method handleMyError(Exception e) also throws exception or say calls System.exit(-1) then obviusly method b() will not be invoked. But if method handleMyError(Exception e) doesn't do anything funcky but just say prints into log, then all is good. Of course, in regular situation without limitation that asks not to use "finally" I would certainly recommend to use "finally"

Comment: since 'try-catch' was not allowed (as stated by the OP), how does this answer contribute?

Comment: try-catch and finally is not allowed for method b() invocation. At least this is what I anderstood from OP's question. Since in my solution b() is not invoked in try-catch-finally in my opinion it answers the question

Comment: if that was so, they wouldn't have been bothered with b() in the catch block, they just would have asked whether he knew about a better place for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute b(); only if the exception is thrown, you should call it on the catch(){} block. If you want to execute it anyway you can put it either on finally {} or after everything **(see edit)**.

- If b(); is very retalated to the exception or you want to use variables initialized inside the try{} block, you should write it on finally{} such like this:

  ```
  try{
        a();
       } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        //what to do if exception was thrown
       } finnaly {
        b();
       }
       //you can also call b(); here instead of inside finnaly
  ```
- If b(); is used to handle the exception then:

  ```
  try{
   a();
  } catch (Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
   b();
  }
  ```

You can also make the method to throw A's exception and handle it in the method which is calling a(); But if you are in the main, you should'nt do that.

**EDIT:** As requested, an exemple of the correct answer that wich the interviewer was asking for:

```
    try{
      a();
    } catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace(); //optional
    }

    b();
```

Comment: no try catch allowed apparently

Comment: The words that make this answer correct are the "or after everything" at the end of the second sentence.  It's  a shame there's no code snippet to match.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem this answer is not correct, seeing it applies techniques that are prohibited. the requirement state that try-catch-finally may not be used, hence, they were looking for something different.

Comment: No @Stultuske, the requirement states that the code that must be run after handling the exception must not occur in the catch block or the finally block.  In other words, the correct answer is that it occurs _after everything_, as Carlos stated, but did not exemplify.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem the code as is, it is written to run "after everything". (in best case scenario's) saying: "after everything" would be the same as replying to a pilot-student who asks you how he should fly "in the air". meaning, this is a non-answer.

Answer (score 0):

To me probably the only concise way to do that without `try-catch-finally` is by using `CompetableFuture` features and dispatch execution of the functions each as a separate task. 
Like this:

```
@Test
public void tryCatchFinallyWithCompletableFuture() throws Exception
{
    CompletableFuture
        .runAsync(
            () -> a()
        )
        .exceptionally(
            (e) -> { System.out.print(e.getMessage()); return null; }
        )
        .thenRun(
            () -> b()
        )
        .get();
}

static void a() {
    throw new IllegalStateException("a()");
}

static void b() {
    System.out.println("...but we continue after a()");
}
```

However, I would seriously consider using this approach anywhere but in a playground project. Besides, you must remember that `a()` and `b()` are executed in a multi-threaded context which may require synchronization for the shared state if any is present.

Answer (score -1):

You need  to execute method in where or finally clause

```
try {
  a(); // getting exception here...
} catch(Exception e) {
  b(); // This method should executed after handling exception
}
```

Comment: no, he's not, since he's not allowed to use try catch